# Finding orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find an orthogonal basis for certain symmetric bilinear form $g$ such that matrix of g is diagonal in these basis.Given basis ${b_1,b_2,b_3}$

I am applying the following process (called Gramm Schmidt I guess, but I am confused because doesnt Gramm Schmidt process apply to only inner product spaces?)

$$u_1=b_1$$
$$u_2=b_2-g(b_2,u_1)u_1$$
$$u_3=b_3-g(b_3,u_1)u_1-g(b_3,u_2)u_2$$

Is there a flaw in this process of finding orthogonal basis?
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: An inner product is just a special case of a bilinear form, and the Gram-Schmidt algorithm can be applied with any bilinear form. Over $\Bbb R$, the only difference is that an orthogonal basis may have elements with norm 0 or norm -1. The number of 0's or -1's will depend on the signature of the bilinear form. Over $\Bbb C$ it doesn't matter: you will get all elements with norm 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have a given Matrix, at first calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then use gram schmidt on the eigenvectors of every eigenvalue (but only for vectors to the same eigenvalue, as the others are orthogonal anyway).